# codeigniter: unable to access object properties

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following output in my view:

```
stdClass Object ( [course_id] => 13 [title] => Design Illustration for Beginners).
```

this is the result of using print_r() on $course object. Here is the code behind it in Model:

```
function loadMyTaughtCourses($email)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);    
        $this->db->from('course');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) 
        { 
          return $query->result(); 
        } else { 
            return FALSE;   
        }   

    }
```

The problem here is I am unable to access the properties only. I did this:

```
foreach($taughtCoursesInfo as &$course)
{
    echo $course->title . "<br>";
}
```

and then I get this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/profile.php

Line Number: 14
```

Any idea why? Usually I do $object->property and that works.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you passed the data from controller to view, it become extracted and all the items from an array become directly accessible through their key name and in your given example I have only one object (as result of `print_r` you mentioned)

```
stdClass Object ( [course_id] => 13 [title] => Design Illustration for Beginners)
```

It's not an array of objects so it's possible to access without the loop, like

```
echo $taughtCoursesInfo->title;
```

Comment: But there are multiple courses retrieved. 2 currently in my table. How can I display both with the $taughtCoursesInfo->title?